# jquery - Bootstrap Remote Tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the [bootstrap remote data](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/bootstrap-remote-data) plugin to populate page in my tabs however the first tab would never populate onload unless I click on another tab and then go back on the first tab. How can I make the first tab load when the page is ready?

Here's the [link to the repository](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/bootstrap-remote-data)

Here's the markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab-v1 tabs-below">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Jan"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Feb"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Mar"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-below">
            <li class="active"><a href="#Jan" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="reports/reportloader/2014-01-01">Jan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Feb" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="reports/reportloader/2014-02-01">Feb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Mar" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="reports/reportloader/2014-03-01">Mar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us how you're attempting to populate the tab.

Comment: This https://github.com/LeaseWeb/bootstrap-remote-data plugin is not compatible with bootstrap 3, bootstrap 3 has tremendous difference with bootstrap 2. 

Actually that plugin builded for bootstrap 2.

Comment: The demo is actually built on Bootstrap 3. I have a working mockup but the only problem is the content of first tab doesn't load automatically. Here's the demo http://leaseweb.github.io/bootstrap-tabs-demo